# Swift error: Can't assign value of type UIColor to type CGColor

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have two input fields in my view, `loginEmailInput` and `loginPasswordInput`.

I'm trying to change the border color. My code in `ViewController.swift` looks like so:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var loginPasswordInput: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var loginEmailInput: UITextField!

    let borderColor : UIColor = UIColor(red:0.39, green:0.76, blue:0.37, alpha:1)
    loginEmailInput.layer.borderColor = borderColor
    loginPasswordInput.layer.borderColor = borderColor

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //etc....
```

However, both these lines show an error:

```
loginEmailInput.layer.borderColor = borderColor
loginPasswordInput.layer.borderColor = borderColor
```

The error is:

> Can't assign value of type UIColor to type CGColor

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: `layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor`? You also don't need the explicit type annotation on your `UIColor`. Although more importantly, those two lines setting the border color need to be in a method, not just floating in the class.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

For a CALayer, use, as an example:

```
UIColor.blue.cgColor
```

In general, layers/ `CALayers` use CG (Core Graphics) colors. While for something like background of the view, you can use something like `view.backgroundColor = .blue` . UIColor is part of UIKit FrameWork (NSObject), CG is part of Core Graphic (CF/ Core Foundation Library)

Note: for very old versions of Swift (Swift 1 and 2), you would have use:

```
UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
```

Comment: A few nitpicks - it's more commonly pluralized "Core Graphics", and `CF` is actually the prefix for classes from the Core _Foundation_ library.

Comment: @CraigOtis absolutely, I have updated my answer, let me now if you have any more suggestions

Comment: Swift 3:
UIColor.black.cgColor

Comment: Swift 3, with custom color: UIColor(red:255/255, green: 144/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1).cgColor

Answer (score 1):

```
imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
```

Answer (score 0):

We can define the color by converting UIcolor to ciColor. With the code below:

```
imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(ciColor: .blue)
```

Comment: please explain your code , what does it do , how does it answer the question

Answer (score 0):

in my Case :
using Custom Color :

```
   view.layer.borderColor = Colors.Mountain.color.cgColor
```